Properties of idempotent matrices.
Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are idempotent matrices ($A^2 = A$ and $B^2 = B$) such that $AB = BA$. It is not hard to show that the only eigenvalues of both matrices can only be $0$ and $1$. In particular we can show that if $M^2 = M$, then $$\{x: Mx = x\} = \text{Col}(M) \quad \text{and} \quad \{x: Mx = 0\} = \text{Null}(M).$$ In other words the $E_1(M) = \text{Col}(M)$ and $E_0(M) = \text{Null}(M)$, where $E_\lambda$ is the set of eigenvectors of $M$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.
Note that when $AB=BA$, the matrix $AB$ is idempotent itself.
Now I am interested in studying $\text{Col}(AB)$ and $\text{Null}(AB)$.
I believe that $\text{Col}(AB) = \text{Col}(A) \cap \text{Col}(B)$. Indeed, if $y \in \text{Col}(AB)$, then we have $$y = ABy = A(By) = B(Ay),$$ so $y \in \text{Col}(A) \cap \text{Col}(B)$. Next if $y \in \text{Col}(A) \cap \text{Col}(B)$, then we know that $A_y = By = y$, so $$y = Ay = ABy,$$ so $y \in \text{Col}(AB)$.
For $\text{Null}(AB)$ I believe that $\text{Null}(AB) = \text{Null}(A) \cap \text{Null}(B)$. Indeed, if $x \in \text{Null}(A) \cap \text{Null}(B)$, then $$ABx = A(0) = 0.$$ So $x \in \text{Null}(AB).$ Now if $x \in \text{Null}(AB)$, then $$Ax = A(Bx + x - Bx) = A(x-Bx) = Ax - ABx = A(Ax-ABx).$$ How can I continue? I believe this is on the right track, but cannot finish.

Your claim about the null spaces is false: Take for example the matrices
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then $AB=BA=0$ and both $A$ and $B$ are idempotent. But $\mathrm{Null}(A)\cap \mathrm{Null}(B)=0$ and $\mathrm{Null}(AB)=\mathbb{F}^2$ (here $\mathbb{F}$ is the ground field).
What you can prove is that $\mathrm{Null}(AB) = \mathrm{Null}(A)+\mathrm{Null}(B)$, and you can prove it using precisely the same idea you showed at the end of your question.
